# Android Button widget hyphenation

Tags: android, xml, button

I have a problem with my project. I use `android.widget.Button`. When  word can not fit in one line in the `Button` then it cut it like this: **Somelon>gword** (where **'>'** is new line). How to fix it? And how to create inner padding for the text because the long word touches the button's borders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code. Where `paddingRight` and `paddingLeft` keep padding of 25dp in right and left. If you want to text on in one line.Then 
you can use `android:singleLine="true"`

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/she_was_good"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingRight="25dp"
     android:paddingLeft="25dp"
     android:ellipsize=”marquee”
     android:text="@string/im_sorry_lol_str" />
```

Read this [post](http://android.okhelp.cz/horizontal-marquee-text-in-button-android-example/)

Comment: No, I dont need singleLine text. If there are two and more words then all right, but if there is only one long word I dont want, but it cut this long words.

Comment: Means you have word "dfffsffsdkfnjdfkfskdfjkf" long and you want to cut it like "dfffsffsdkfn" this???

Comment: Means that I have word `someLongWord` and it cut it like this `someLongWor >>> d` and I dont want to do it.

Comment: I updated code. You can add       android:ellipsize=”marquee”   in you code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the property `android:singleLine="true"` and `android:padding="10dp"` to your button widget.